# Rebinding a port to datagram socket on a difftent IP

Tags: java, network-programming

In my application I hyave created a datagarm socket and binded a port say 9999 to ip 192.168.173.1 now i want to bind the port to a new ip say 192.168.173.2 
but i am not able to do it 
Steps i followed

```
1 DatagramSocket s= new DatagramSocket(port,ip1);
2 s.disconnect();

s.close();

s= new DatagramSocket(port,ip2);
```

but this gives a

```
java,net,BindException :Address already in use : Cannot bind
```

Any insight would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you checked the following: 1. port 9999 is free on IP2, 2. IP2 is pingable 3. you have permissions to access IP2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid exceptions when trying to unbind and rebind, you would set each created socket as reusable. In order to do so, you MUST create an **unbound** socket:

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
s.setReuseAddress(true);
s.bind(someSocketAddress);
```

More info:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)

P.S. The timeout period that is the main reason for a BindException under such circumstances when using a TCP may not apply to UDP sockets, but the SO_REUSE should allow you to rebind instantly anyway.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)

Here are a few examples:

```
final int port = 55880;
```

A) No reuse, no close = Address already in use

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port));

s = new DatagramSocket(null);
s.setReuseAddress(true);
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
```

B) Reuse, no close = no complaints

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
s.setReuseAddress(true);
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port));

s = new DatagramSocket(null);
s.setReuseAddress(true);
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
```

C) No reuse, close = no complaints (for datagram sockets only)

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port));
s.close();

s = new DatagramSocket(null);
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
s.close();
```

Comment: It did not work i setted the socket reuse as true but the same exception poops up again

Comment: If all of the sockets that bind on that specific port are reusable, you cannot get a bind exception.

Comment: there is only one port and i am getting an exception

Comment: Then it would be nice if you would post all the code that deals with socket creation/closing.

Answer (score 0):

Very important - maybe some users missed that:

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

The proper line from the examples above works fine:

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
```